# Class Instantiation only works globally but not in set up

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I have an issue where the order of an object's instantiation effects the functionality of my system. All the following code compile but only one actuates the stepper. I also want to point out that the Arduino [Stepper library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StepperConstructor) specifies the class be instantiated before set up. I assume the same reason applies for the [TMC26XStepper](https://github.com/trinamic/TMC26XStepper).

Research on my own makes me think the opposite would be true. My understanding is that objects instantiated before setup() are called before the Arduino runtime environment init() is called. This would cause methods like pinMode() to not be available yet. Reflecting on the default Arduino stepper library again the constructor calls pinMode() which seems wrong.

Why does it have to be in this order?

Working code that instantiates the TMC26XStepper class before setup():

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TMC26XStepper.h>
TMC26XStepper tmc26xStepper = TMC26XStepper(200, 2, 6, 7, 800);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  tmc26xStepper.setSpreadCycleChopper(0, 24, 8, 6, 0);
  tmc26xStepper.setRandomOffTime(0);
  tmc26xStepper.setMicrosteps(16);
  tmc26xStepper.setStallGuardThreshold(2, 0);
  tmc26xStepper.setSpeed(400);
  tmc26xStepper.start();
  moveNSteps(tmc26xStepper, 1000);
  moveNSteps(tmc26xStepper, -1000);
}
void loop() {
}

void moveNSteps(TMC26XStepper stepper, int steps) {
  int microSteps = 16;
  stepper.step(steps * microSteps);
  while (stepper.getStepsLeft() != 0 && stepper.isMoving()) {
    stepper.move();
  }
}
```

This code compiles however the stepper motor does not spin. The only difference is where the TMC26XStepper object is instantiated:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TMC26XStepper.h>

void setup() {
  TMC26XStepper tmc26xStepper = TMC26XStepper(200, 2, 6, 7, 800);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  tmc26xStepper.setSpreadCycleChopper(0, 24, 8, 6, 0);
  tmc26xStepper.setRandomOffTime(0);
  tmc26xStepper.setMicrosteps(16);
  tmc26xStepper.setStallGuardThreshold(2, 0);
  tmc26xStepper.setSpeed(400);
  tmc26xStepper.start();
  moveNSteps(tmc26xStepper, 1000);
  moveNSteps(tmc26xStepper, -1000);
}
void loop() {
}

void moveNSteps(TMC26XStepper stepper, int steps) {
  int microSteps = 16;
  stepper.step(steps * microSteps);
  while (stepper.getStepsLeft() != 0 && stepper.isMoving()) {
    stepper.move();
  }
}
```

This also compiles but does not turn the motor:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TMC26XStepper.h>
TMC26XStepper *tmc26xStepper
void setup() {
  tmc26XStepper= new TMC26XStepper(200, 2, 6, 7, 800);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  tmc26xStepper->setSpreadCycleChopper(0, 24, 8, 6, 0);
  tmc26xStepper->setRandomOffTime(0);
  tmc26xStepper->setMicrosteps(16);
  tmc26xStepper->setStallGuardThreshold(2, 0);
  tmc26xStepper->setSpeed(400);
  tmc26xStepper->start();
  moveNSteps(tmc26xStepper, 1000);
  moveNSteps(tmc26xStepper, -1000);
}
void loop() {
}
void moveNSteps(TMC26XStepper* stepper, int steps) {
  int microSteps = 16;
  stepper->step(steps * microSteps);
  while (stepper->getStepsLeft() != 0 && stepper->isMoving()) {
    stepper->move();
  }
}
```

Edit1:
Hardware used

Arduino uno

[TOS100 Stepper Shield](https://blog.trinamic.com/2013/02/01/getting-started-with-the-tos-100-arduino-stepper-motor-shield/)

[User manual for tmc260a chip on the shield](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC260_datasheet_Rev2.12.pdf)

Comment: Learn about class instantiation and variable scopes.

Comment: The working example uses a global declaration just like the 3rd example. Yet the 3rd example doesn’t work. Also the second example is completely contained in set up. So I’m not sure your comment is of any help

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.. even if in the second case the stepper is a local variable inside setup, calling the function from inside the setup should work considering the scope of the variables (according to my limited knowledges). The same for the pointer..

I did some tries using the simulator as I do not have an Arduino and a stepper/servo here right now.
The 3 cases worked for me on [wokwi Arduino simulator](https://wokwi.com/arduino/libraries/Servo/Sweep), but I am not sure if the simulator really represents the real Arduino behavior.
Here is the example code I simulated using pointers:

```
#include <Servo.h>
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup() {
  Servo * myservo = new Servo();  // create servo object to control a servo
  myservo->attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  move(myservo);
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);
}

void move(Servo * myfbservo){
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myfbservo->write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}
```

Comment: Your simulation is correct! However, the stepper motor has an external driver that is configured during the constructor. I believe this could be a big difference I forgot to mention. I updated the question with the hardware used