# Program don't work correctly when object is changed to object pointer

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I use [example](https://github.com/madpilot/mDNSResolver/blob/master/examples/mDNSResolver.ino) of [mDNSResolver](https://github.com/madpilot/mDNSResolver) library to resolve a local Host name to IP address as following :

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <mDNSResolver.h>

#define WIFI_AP         "myap"
#define WIFI_PASS       "mypass"
#define NAME_TO_RESOLVE "myhost.local"

using namespace mDNSResolver;

WiFiClient wifiClient;
WiFiUDP udp;
Resolver resolver(udp);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  int WiFiCounter = 0;
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_AP);

  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASS);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && WiFiCounter < 30) {
    delay(1000);
    WiFiCounter++;
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.print("Resolving ");
  Serial.println(NAME_TO_RESOLVE);

  resolver.setLocalIP(WiFi.localIP());
  
  IPAddress ip = resolver.search(NAME_TO_RESOLVE);
  if(ip != INADDR_NONE) {
    Serial.print("Resolved: ");
    Serial.println(ip);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Not resolved");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Required to clear the UDP buffer, as we can't unjoin a multicast group yet
  resolver.loop();
}
```

It work as i expect i.e the IP is resolved successfully and printed on serial console as :

> Resolved: [RESOLVED IP ADDRESS, FOR EXAMPLE:] 192.168.1.33

But when i change `resolver` object to a pointer as following :

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <mDNSResolver.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

#define WIFI_AP "myap"
#define WIFI_PASS "mypass"
#define NAME_TO_RESOLVE "myhost.local"

using namespace mDNSResolver;

WiFiClient wifiClient;
WiFiUDP udp;
Resolver *resolver;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  int WiFiCounter = 0;

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_AP);

  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASS);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && WiFiCounter < 30)
  {
    delay(1000);
    WiFiCounter++;
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  resolver = new Resolver(udp);
  resolver->setLocalIP(WiFi.localIP());
  IPAddress ip = resolver->search(NAME_TO_RESOLVE);
  if (ip != INADDR_NONE)
  {
    Serial.print("Resolved: ");
    Serial.println(ip);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Not resolved");
  }

}

void loop()
{
  // Required to clear the UDP buffer, as we can't unjoin a multicast group yet
  resolver->loop();

}
```

The program can't resolve any local host name anymore and following statement will print on serial console :

> Not resolved

The `if... else...` statement in `setup()` function determine either IP is resolved successfully or no :

```
  if (ip != INADDR_NONE)
  {
    Serial.print("Resolved: ");
    Serial.println(ip);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Not resolved");
  }
```

Did i use object pointer correctly? If no, how must i fix that?

Comment: Please remove the "C++: " from the title, that's what tags are for. Further, you're doing some serial communication there, too, is that relevant? Also, read [ask]. In particular, you don't describe the error you get at all, just "don't work" is not a description. BTW: When and how do you call `loop()`? It looks unused...

Comment: @Ulrich Arduino development environment is C++ with a few training wheels. There's an assumed call to `setup()` and a periodic call to `loop()` in particular, with no direct access to `main` - so Arduino programming ends up with a lot of global variables. It's not inherently bad, because these programs aren't supposed to be very large anyway, so globals are little more grokable.

Comment: Can you please show the exact, specific, copy-and-pasted code that you have successfully run with the expected result? Right now, all I know is that the code you have shown doesn't work, I don't know what "doesn't work" means, and I don't know what the code that worked does look like. Also specify what "working" means. That means describe the specific observable output that you expect versus what you see.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I edit my post for you

Answer (score -2):

Call `resolver = new Resolver(udp);` before setup():

```
WiFiClient wifiClient;
WiFiUDP udp;
Resolver *resolver = new Resolver(udp);
```

Edit1:
For some reason, some boards must to be configured globally, and even if you pass a pointer to the object created it does not work. This is a behavior that is under discussion yet, as you can see in this post:
[Class Instantiation only works globally but not in set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68593297/class-instantiation-only-works-globally-but-not-in-set-up/68598100?noredirect=1#comment121239635_68598100)

So that is why I suggesting to declare and instantiate it globally.

Comment: Maybe add some more context as to why that would help?

Comment: I change it but my problem is not resolved.

Comment: Sorry, I write the suggestion when I was in a hurry. The motivation of the suggestion was added in the Edit1.